# Passing connection string from linqpad to custom library causes login failure

Tags: c#, dll, connection-string, linqpad

I am writing a linqpad script for migrating data into a db from an excel file. Once the data has been imported it needs to be synchronized between multiple dbs. This has been done in a dll as the functionality is used elsewhere.

My issue is that when passing a connection string to my dll from linqpad I get the message Login failed for user 'xxxxxxx'. As far as I can tell it is because the password for the SQL authentication is not passed in the connection string. IS there any way to make linqpad include the password in the connection string:

```
SyncController syncController = new SyncController(this.Connection.ConnectionString);
syncController.SyncAll();
```

If it is at all possible I want to avoid forcing the person who will be running this to update a password variable when running this. Thanks.

Comment: You should look at [Windows Authentication](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms144284.aspx)

Comment: I don't think you should use Linqpad for scripts that others will run anyway. Create a small custom exe in which they can enter their password.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're right: the password will disappear from the connection string after the connection is opened. This is a [feature of the .NET Framework](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/89211k9b%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), and is not specific to LINQPad.

There are two workarounds. First, you can capture the connection string as the first line in your LINQPad script, before querying any data:

```
string cxString = this.Connection.ConnectionString;
```

The other workaround is to add the following text to your connection string:

```
Persist Security Info=true
```

To do this in LINQPad, right-click the connection and choose **Properties**. Click **Advanced**, and enter the additional connection string text into the box provided.

Comment: Perfect answer thanks. Got the connection string in the first line in my script and that totally solved my issue. Thanks.